# ReCaptcha JSP 'Cannot load URL' on processing

Tags: jsp, recaptcha

Following instructions in this url: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/java

I'm trying to use reCaptcha with the JSP plugin using the code they provide on the page.

My initial page works fine - the captcha is displayed and I can enter the text and submit.

The problem is with my processing page which is returning an error:

**net.tanesha.recaptcha.ReCaptchaException: Cannot load URL: Connection timed out: connect at net.tanesha.recaptcha.http.SimpleHttpLoader.httpPost(SimpleHttpLoader.java:89) at net.tanesha.recaptcha.ReCaptchaImpl.checkAnswer(ReCaptchaImpl.java:61) at org.apache.jsp.Captchas.processServer_jsp._jspService(processServer_jsp.java:7...**

So it says it 'Cannot load URL' - is this a problem with the company's firewall?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is the problem with your network connectivity . You can conclude it by checking your connection with `google.com`.

If you are able to connect with google in your browser amidst of the firewall , you can  successfully run the captacha code